# mimic "if constexpr" behavior, impossible?

Tags: c++, templates, if-statement, constexpr, c++17

My compiler doesn't support `if constexpr`,        but I am captivated by its benefit.
I must have it - even it might be a fake one.

This code is my attempt to mimic `if constexpr` behavior.
The objective is to make the lines (###) appear in only 1 function :-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<bool Flag,typename F> constexpr typename std::enable_if<!Flag, void>::type iter_(F f,int i1){
    f(i1); //No!  The compiler still tried to compile even Flag=true
}
template<bool Flag,typename F> constexpr typename std::enable_if<Flag, void>::type iter_(F f,int i1){   }
template<bool Flag,typename F> constexpr typename std::enable_if<Flag, void>::type iter_(F f,int i1,int i2){
    f(i1,i2); //No!  The compiler still tried to compile even Flag=false
}
template<bool Flag,typename F> constexpr typename std::enable_if<!Flag, void>::type iter_(F f,int i1,int i2){}

template<bool Flag,typename F> constexpr void fff(  F f  ){
    for(int n=0;n<5;n++){//fake loop, the real situation is very complex
        //### some horror code appeared here, but omitted
        if(Flag){//attempt to mimic "if constexpr"
            iter_<true>(f,1,2);
        }else{
            iter_<false>(f,3);
        }
    }
}
```

This is its usage:-

```
template<typename F> constexpr void fff1(  F f  ){fff<false>(f);} //usage
template<typename F> constexpr void fff2(  F f  ){fff<true>(f);} //usage

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    auto f1=[&](int a){
        cout<<a<<" ";   
    };
    auto f2=[&](int a,int b){
        cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;  
    };
    fff1(f1);
    fff2(f2);
    return 0;
}
```

**I got compile error :**

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr typename std::enable_if<Flag, void>::type iter_(F, int, int) [with bool Flag = true; F = main()::<lambda(int)>; typename std::enable_if<Flag, void>::type = void]':
prog.cpp:16:18:   required from 'constexpr void fff(F) [with bool Flag = false; F = main()::<lambda(int)>]'
prog.cpp:22:61:   required from 'constexpr void fff1(F) [with F = main()::<lambda(int)>]'
prog.cpp:33:9:   required from here
prog.cpp:9:3: error: no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(int)>) (int&, int&)'
  f(i1,i2);
   ^
prog.cpp:9:3: note: candidate: void (*)(int) <conversion>
prog.cpp:9:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
```

From the error, it is clear to me that even when a function has **std::enable_if[ *effective* FALSE]**,
 the compiler still compiled code that inside the function.
 - That is bad.

Which parts do I have to edit?
...  or are there any alternatives?
... or is it not possible to mimic `if constexpr` at all (that is the reason why it is introduced finally)?

Comment: yes, all the code inside a template must be valid. So no there is no way to have an `if` that has a branch that is not valid for a template and still be able to instantiate for that template.

Comment: What `if constexpr` are you talking about? There is no such thing in C++11...

Comment: @rubenvb if constexpr is going to be in C++17

Comment: @Eugene The question was at the time of that comment still tagged c++11.

Comment: Specialize, don't use `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0128r1.html

> Can't we do this with existing language features?
>
> John Spicer suggested in c++std-ext-17099 that polymorphic lambdas
>   combined with a decision-making template would provide an adequate
>   facility without a need to add new language features. The invocation
>   of that decision-making template looks roughly like this:
>
> ```
> template <int arg, typename ... Args> int do_something(Args... args) {
>     return static_if<sizeof...(args)>::get(
>         [](auto x, auto y) { return x+y; },
>         [](auto x) { return *x; })(args...);
> }
> ```
>
> Now, in comparison, with the proposed language facility, we do
>
> ```
> template <int arg, typename ... Args> int do_something(Args... args) {
>     constexpr if (sizeof...(args)) {
>         return (args + ...);
>     } constexpr_else {
>         return *args...;
>     }
> }
> ```

Now this is sort of a an alternative. It gets more complicated if the different branches return different types.

Moreover,

> I must point out some things here:
>
> - I can return, break, continue and goto from within a constexpr if
>     block. I can not do that from within the lambda.
> - While I am a big
>     proponent of using lambdas to create new control facilities, I find
>     the constexpr if solution infinitely more readable.

Further,

> Richard Smith explained the following:
>
> > Right, when a function template is instantiated, all of the
> >     declarations/statements/expressions within it are instantiated, and
> >     that includes pieces inside local classes, generic lambdas, and so on.
> >
> > This instantiation of generic lambda bodies is in fact necessary for
> >     our language semantics -- computing the captures of a generic lambda
> >     within a function template specialization relies on us having already
> >     instantiated the complete closure type and its call operator template
> >     to the point that we know where the odr-uses are within the
> >     non-dependent full-expressions within the body.
>
> In contrast, the intent of constexpr if is that the branch not taken
>   is not instantiated.

Comment: Note that Boost.Hana has such a feature: [`hana::if_`](https://boostorg.github.io/hana/#tutorial-integral-branching). As far as instantiation goes, it does not instantiate untaken branches if they are generic lambdas. Based on Richard's comment, there's probably some more code behind that.